# EC2 ssh-add identity doesn't "stick"

Tags: linux, git, ssh, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

I'm trying to connect my Atlassian BitBucket with an AWS EC2.
I followed all the right steps and it's working. The one thing that got me into trouble was launching the ssh-agent with eval `ssh-agent -s` and then ssh-add mybitbucket.pub to add the identity.

However, the issue is that the identity does not persist. Meaning that if log back in, in order to do any git operations, I have to do eval `ssh-agent -s` and ssh-add mybitbucket.pub again.

*[root@ip-10-0-1-112 themes]# ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.*

Any recommended workarounds?

Steps taken so far:

1. Login EC2
2. Sudo su -
3. ssh-keygen -t rsa
4. eval `ssh-agent -s`
5. ssh-add mybitbucket.pub
6. copy the key in BitBucket's web interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the only time the EC2 instance needs the key when you are ssh'd into the instance?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where you only need the key when you are `ssh`'d to the instance, you can set up `ssh-agent` forwarding. This means that when you connect to a specified host, the remote server is allowed to use the keys from your local `ssh-agent` in order to connect to things, such as the bitbucket account.

So, what you could do is add your public key to the BitBucket account, which would then allow you to access BitBucket via `ssh` because your local machine has your private key. Then, by enabling `ssh-agent` forwarding, when you `ssh` to the EC2 instance, you allow that instance to use your private key access BitBucket without ever storing your private key on the instance.

Here's an article on how to set this up:

https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/

In short, add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host example.com
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Where `example.com` is the public IP of your AWS instance, or the EIP assigned to it, etc.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked! Thank you.